# Struts2 Iterate value from a textfield

Tags: struts2

I am trying to iterate over the textfield's value, for eg. 5. Is there a way to get the value?

I have a textfield with value 5:

```
<s:textfield 
  theme="simple" 
  cssClass="form-control" 
  name="instCount" 
  value="5" 
  style="width:25%;" 
  onkeyup="javascript:isNumber(this);"
/>
```

I need to iterate the value 5:

```
<s:if test='<s:property value="%{instCount}"/> > 0'>
    <s:iterator value='<s:property value="%{instCount}"/>' var="count" status="countStatus"> 
    </s:iterator>
</s:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest JSP tags like that, and it appears that you haven't wrapped your head around OGNL or ELs in general, even though you use it correctly in the `<s:property>` tag.

Let's take a step back: what is this doing?

```
<s:property value="%{instCount}" />
```

- It's referring to an action property named `instCount`.
- How? Via the OGNL expression `%{instCount}`.

How does the `<s:if>` tag work? By evaluating an OGNL expression in the `test` property. Ah, OGNL expression, which we've already seen.

```
<s:if test='instCount > 0'>
```

How does the `<s:iterator>` tag work? By evaluating an OGNL expression in the `value` tag.

```
<s:iterator value='%{instCount}' etc...>
```

I would *highly* recommend taking some time to figure out the framework you're working in, even a minor reading of the documentation (and a basic understanding of how JSP works) will be *highly* beneficial, and avoid questions like this.